# links doesn't work with swiper fade on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade, swiper.js

I'm trying to make a site with the plugin swiper and the "fade" effect.
The problem is that when I enable "fade", it makes all my links and text not clickable, like if it was an image (and I can't select text either)

here is my script:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        direction: 'vertical',
        effect: 'fade',
        fade: { crossFade: true },
        SimulateTouch: false,
        mousewheelControl: true
    });
```

But when I delete 'effect: fade', it works (except no fade, but scroll instead)

Sorry if I'm not clear, thank's for your answers.

Comment: Could u post the html or link to jsfiddle?

Comment: So sorry, I can't manage to put it on jsfiddle so I put it on dropbox :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zmdq96o3hbmj7ya/AAD86iLvcpBD_OjvHI5h-9Ata?dl=0

I know It sucks, sorry :(